# Need help on producer and consumer thread in python

Tags: python, multithreading

I wanted to create the consumer and producer thread in python simultaneously, where producer thread will append the queue and consumer thread retrieves the item which stored in the queue. And I need to start the consumer thread along with producer. Consumer thread should wait till the queue gets an item. And it should terminate when there is no item in queue. I am new to python, please help on this.

Requirements:

If there is a list of 10 numbers, producer thread should insert the queue with one item, and consumer thread should retrieve the number. Both thread should start simultaneously  .

```
from queue import Queue
import threading
import time

class producer(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, list_of_numbers):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.list_items = list_of_numbers

    def run(self):
        for i in self.list_items:
            queue.put(str(i))

class consumer(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        while queue.not_empty:
            queue_ret = queue.get()
            print("Retrieved", queue_ret)


queue = Queue()
producers = producer([10,20,5,4,3,2,1])
consumers = consumer()

producers.start()
consumers.start()
producers.join()
consumers.join()
```

Comment: I have tried with Queue, but I was not able to terminate the consumer thread.

Comment: What @FunkySayu said. Also, have you looked into a multiprocessing queue for this task? Python handles this exact scenario.

Comment: what does your code look like

Comment: I have used threading for this. But consumer thread fail sometimes if its starts earlier than producer thread, and it gets queue empty, And I have also tried with the condition in thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put a special item once you are done:

```
_im_done = object()

class producer(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        '''feed the consumer until you are done'''
        queue.put(_im_done)

class consumer(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        while True:
            queue_ret = queue.get()
            if queue_ret is _im_done:
                break
            '''normal execution'''
```

If there are multiple consumers, then you have to put the item back before you stop:

```
class consumer(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        while True:
            queue_ret = queue.get()
            if queue_ret is _im_done:
                queue.put(_im_done)
                break
            '''normal execution'''
```

Answer (score 0):

`queue.get()` is blocking. If there are no items in queue it will just get stuck there. You should use `while True: queue.get(block=False)` and handle Empty exception and exit.

Ok full code to clear confusion

```
from Queue import Queue, Empty
import threading
import time

started = False
running = True

class producer(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, list_of_numbers):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.list_items = list_of_numbers

    def run(self):
        started = True
        for i in self.list_items:
            queue.put(str(i))
        running = False

class consumer(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        while not started:
            sleep(0)

        while running:
            try:
                queue_ret = queue.get(block=False)
            except Empty:
                sleep(0)
                continue
            print("Retrieved", queue_ret)


queue = Queue()
producers = producer([10,20,5,4,3,2,1])
consumers = consumer()

producers.start()
consumers.start()
producers.join()
consumers.join()
```

Comment: The consumer could get scheduled before the producer produces anything. Then it would exit immediately. Also the production could take longer that the consumption. Then this solution would also fail.

Comment: @Andrey , I have one more issue when using the above code, what if I consumer thread starts earlier than producer and it will find queue empty and gets exit. Is there any way to handle using 'condition'.

Comment: @Kay that was about stopping thread and yes this is only correct way to consumer threads properly. Because OP's code is not thread safe. If there are 2 consumer threads, they can get into race condition over last item and other thread will get stuck forever.

Comment: running should defaults to False, and be set True when producer is done?

Comment: I still don't see how this should work if the consumer starts before the producer.

Comment: @NeoWang why? `running = False` means that thread should stop running.

Comment: @Andrey The consumer exits its `while` when producer is done, is that what you want?

Comment: @Kay fixed. I need 2 vars

Comment: Still won't work if it takes longer to produce the items than the consume them. Maybe the producer reads a datagram stream and the consumer prints the data. (This is not an contrived example.)

Comment: @Kay I updated serveral times, not sure if you were looking at final version. I am fairly convinced that the current one will function properly in all scenarios.

Comment: Your last edit where you use `continue` instead of `return` works, but uses a busy loop, which is not very advisable.

Comment: @Kay I agree, you can use threading.Event() to avoid busy waiting. `sleep(0)` is good enough I would say. It will just yield to next thread and don't waste much of CPU resources.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [queue module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html) directly. The documentation contains an example for your use case. As a side note, the module is named `Queue` in Python 2.

However threading in Python won't get your program any faster if it is CPU bound, in this case you may use [multiprocessing module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) instead (in IO bound cases threading may be more viable since threads are often cheaper). Mutiprocessing module also provides a safe queue implementation named `multiprocessing.Queue`.